# USB Switch not working with Macbook Pro 2018

Tags: mac, windows, hardware

I am a complete newbie Mac user and I am trying to set up a PC/Mac workstation sharing keyboard, mouse, and headset.

I bought this [USB hub](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/UGREEN-Printer-Scanner-Keyboard-Headset/dp/B01N6GD9JO/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1LH30GN1H1I2E&keywords=usb+switch+mac&qid=1645536394&refinements=p_76%3A419122031&rnid=419121031&rps=1&sprefix=usb+switch+mac%2Caps%2C73&sr=8-3)
and tried to connect it to my Mac with this [USB Type C to USB A cable](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Amazon-Basics-Cable-Metre-Black/dp/B01GGKYKQM/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=amazon+basics+usb+typ+c+kabel&qid=1645536565&sprefix=usb+to+usb+c+cable+amazon+basic%2Caps%2C74&sr=8-3).

On Windows, everything works flawlessly, but on the Mac, I cannot even get a signal from anything hooked at that switch. What am I doing wrong? Is it the wrong cable?

Comment: I would image the USB 2.0 cable is missing the pins that a would be included in a USB 3.0 cable. Maybe you would be better off with [this one](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Amazon-Basics-Standard-Generation-Braided/dp/B07D7S5CH7/ref=sr_1_15?crid=1CYARLZRNKQP5&keywords=usb%2Btyp%2Bc%2Bauf%2Busb%2Ba%2B3%2C0%2Bkabel%2B0%2C9%2Bmeter%2Bschwarz&qid=1645540516&sprefix=usb%2Btype%2Bc%2Bto%2Busb%2Ba%2B3.0%2Bcable%2B0.9%2Bmetre%2Bblack%2Caps%2C264&sr=8-15&th=1).

Comment: @DavidAnderson  I ordered one and it just arrived, but sadly the same issue still persist. Guess i will return the switch and try looking for another. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Have you considered using [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12) to share the keyboard, mouse and display with the PC from the Mac?

Comment: I was considering [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) but tbh i would rather have one device turned off and work fully on my Mac. Because of Home Office, i am working 12 hours on one device and mixing private with work is really exhausting. I wanna have a clear line that's the main reason.